# DEV C++ incompatible types in assignment of `const char[10]' to `char[21]'

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct Infor{
       char name[21];

       }infot[4];
int main()
{
    infot[0].name="PROGRAM 1";
    cout<<infot[0].name;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is used to initialize a string into a structure containing a char variable.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `strcpy()` to copy c-style strings.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
struct Infor{
       char name[21];
       int acn;
       int pin;
       int balance;
       }infot[4];
int main()
{
    strcpy(infot[0].name, "PROGRAM 1");
    cout<<infot[0].name;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, `std::string` may be useful.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Infor{
       string name;
       int acn;
       int pin;
       int balance;
       }infot[4];
int main()
{
    infot[0].name = "PROGRAM 1";
    cout<<infot[0].name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not really good practice to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: Thanks man.
Works like a charm.
And I'm new to programming so why should i not use using namspace std;?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).